# Unable to setup Calico on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, calico

Trying to set up Calico on-premises Kubernetes cluster.

Initializing cluster `kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16`
Using `https://docs.projectcalico.org/manifests/calico.yaml` manifest.

```
~# calicoctl node status
Calico process is running.

IPv4 BGP status
+---------------+-------------------+-------+----------+---------+
| PEER ADDRESS  |     PEER TYPE     | STATE |  SINCE   |  INFO   |
+---------------+-------------------+-------+----------+---------+
| 10.25.13.69   | node-to-node mesh | start | 13:49:12 | Connect |
+---------------+-------------------+-------+----------+---------+
```

calico-node complains:
`calico/node is not ready: BIRD is not ready: BGP not established with 10.25.13.69`

What `Connect` actually means? Where to look for the problem? Could it be related to the multiple `kubeadm reset`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As nodes had different network interfaces, `calico-node` autodetected different networks on nodes. To fix this I added `IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD` env var to `calico-node` `DaemonSet`. In my case I used these env var values:

```
   # Auto-detect the BGP IP address.
   - name: IP
     value: "autodetect"
   - name: IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD
     value: cidr=10.0.0.0/8
```